# Flutter SingleChildScrollView will not scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I cannot seem to get my screen to scroll. I have tried a few variations of the following code but I have not been able to get it to work. I also tried it with a ListView that did not work very well either. Admittedly, I did not try to troubleshoot the ListView for very long because I was assuming the issue was being caused by something else. I have looked on SO and seen a few questions about this topic and they helped me fix some issues, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I do not get any error messages or anything, my screen simply does not scroll. Below you will see the general layout of my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
class _TripPackagesState extends State<TripPackages> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(...),
                  GestureDetector(...),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream:
                    Firestore.instance.collection('trip_package').snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> docSnapshot) {
                  if (!docSnapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
                  final int docCount = docSnapshot.data.documents.length;
                  return GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: docCount,
                    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot document =
                          docSnapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(...),
                              Row(...),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(...),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `primary: false` in your `GridView.builder`

Comment: Welcome to SO!. That solution worked. I can't believe it was something that simple! I spent more time on that problem than I am willing to admit. I can't believe it was such a simple solution. Thanks Will!

Comment: I've faced the exact same problem before and probably spent a similar amount of time trying to figure it out! Glad to help!